# Insert data in virtuemart_orderstates while installing plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, virtuemart

I need support on Joomla 3.8.13 plugin Virtuemart. I want to insert new values in `virtuemart_orderstates` table at the time of my plugin installation.

as viretuemart inserts values in virtuemart_orderstates at time of plug installation like

**
*1 COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_STATUS_CANCELLED*
*2 COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_STATUS_COMPLETED*
**

so i wan to insert my Custom status in this table at time of creating payment gateway plugin.

Comment: This is not at all clear, and is likely to be put on hold. Please edit it to describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @user291467 When you have Joomla-specific questions, please post them in Joomla Stack Exchange to reach a dedicated Joomla audience.  This will also make JSE a one-stop-shop for researchers seeking Joomla solutions.  (and if more Joomla questions land in JSE than here, maybe Amit will spend more time there.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have a script.php file in your plugin installation. This will run when the plugin is installed. There are 4 methods in the class declaration that runs when the plugin is installed and one method when it is uninstalled. 
These are `preflight, install, update, postflight and uninstall`.

**`Preflight`**
This is the method that runs before installation. Suppose you are creating a plugin for some component and without that component your plugin is useless. So you need to confirm if the component exists, then only installation should proceed else throw some exception.

**`Install`**
Install is executed after the Joomla install database scripts have completed. When you are installing you need to put your sql files here.

**`Update`**
Update is executed after the Joomla update database scripts have completed. Returning 'false' will abort the update and undo any changes already made. When you are updating your plugin your update script should be here.

**`postflight`**
This is executed after all the other 3 are executed. Postflight cannot cause an abort of the Joomla install but the previous 3 methods can roll back installation.

**`Uninstall`**
As the name suggests it is used during uninstallation. if you want to remove any database file that cannot be removed from xml uninstall or you want to delete any image folder etc you can do during uninstallation. It is better just to display a uninstall message here.

Inside your script.php file

```
    <?php
    // No direct access
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    /*
     * Script file for the YourPlugin  
     */
    class plgsystemYourPlugin{

      /*
       * Method to run after the plugin during install and after preflight action is completed.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      function install($parent){
        // For Testing Purposes
        run your database script here
      }
    }
?>
```

Also script.php should be included in your xml installer file inside a script tag

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply ,
 i am new to Joomla can you please share a working demo it will be a great help.,or you can share the placement of this tag in XML
1 Should i have to create another xml.

Comment: This link will help you https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file